# Picture not align

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanna my t-shirt align with the others but after the ranking 10 , the t-shirt is not align.
I'm trying to do something with space between but it doesn't work. even with some margin there is still a difference .
Do you know how i can do that ?

My code

```
renderRanking = () => {
    return this.state.ranking.map((element) => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            marginBottom: 5,
            flexDirection: 'row',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
          }}>
          <View>
            <Text
              adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}
              style={{
                fontSize: 23,
                color: 'white',
              }}>
              {this.state.ranking.indexOf(element) + 1}
              <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}>
                {' '}
               
                <Image
                  style={{width: 40, height: 40}}
                  source={{
                    uri: 'http://localhost:8080/' + element.logo,
                  }}
                />
              </Text>
            </Text>
          </View>

         
        </View>
      );
    });
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try `alignItems: 'center'` in main view.